# how to get power estimation using xpower

Tags: verilog, fpga, xilinx-ise, synopsys-vcs

I have been working on a class project using Verilog. I had to create a circuit and then calculate the power that the circuit uses. I have been trying to do it using Xpower Analyzer I follow the instruction to create the vcd file, compile and synthesize the code using  Xilinx ISE 14.7 . Everything goes well until the result shows up. I received 0 power consumption from the clock. I try to constrains the clock and it only give me a increment in dynamic power from 0 to 0.009, but not luck in the clock. Also, I try Xpower in my personal computer and at my university computer lab, so I don't think that it is a software bug.
Moreover, I have try different design such as a simple alu, register etc. Nonetheless, I still getting the same power result.

More information:

- Testbench runs well and does what I want
- I declare clock like: *module toptrafficlight(
  clock,rst,output );*
- List item: I have constrained the clock to 20ns
- Timing phase = 0. After synthesis (not sure what this means)
- Warrnings from:
- HDLCompiler:413 - Line 86: Result of 5-bit expression is truncated to fit in 4-bit target.
- PhysDesignRules:372 - Gated clock. Clock net main_gated_clk is sourced by a combinatorial pin. This is not good design practice. Use the CE pin to control the loading of data into the flip-flop.

[Power result from Xpower Analyzer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YRxRy.png)

My questions are?

1. is it a way to setup the clock? which I think might be the cause of the problem
2. is there anything else needed to be done beside getting the VCD file and synthesize the code?
3. any other ideas, examples or tutorial?

Answer (score 0):

The screenshot shows that the design is very small, so it's not a big surprise for clock power to be smaller than 1mW. Xilinx also provides an Excel sheet for power estimation. It can be used for a quick tryout to see what circumstances make the clock power significant.

[Xilinx Power Estimator (XPE)](https://www.xilinx.com/products/technology/power/xpe.html)